# Выбор знаков в предложении с однородным рядом и обобщающим словом?

Tags: однородные-члены, вставная-конструкция, обобщающее-слово

*В Бергене все было по-старому. Все, **что могло приглушить звуки**, – ковры, портьеры и мягкую мебель – Григ давно убрал из дома*. (К. Паустовский).

**По какому правилу** обособлен однородный ряд (вставные конструкции или обобщающие слова)?

Сравнить (в учебных текстах): *Все, **что могло приглушить звуки**: ковры, портьеры и мягкую мебель – Григ давно убрал из дома.*

Двоеточие можно **приравнять** к сочетанию "запятая и тире"?

Спасибо.

Comment: Здесь вероятно запятая требуется левой частью, однако, замена на двоеточие - это странно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все, что могло приглушить звуки: ковры, портьеры и мягкую мебель – Григ давно убрал из дома.

Если однородные члены предложения, стоящие после обобщающего слова, не заканчивают собой предложения, то перед ними ставится двоеточие, а после — тире: **Разве все эти вещи: карандаш в оправе, записная книжка, часы, фотографический аппарат — не говорят больше всяких слов об интересном госте? (Пришв.); Везде: над головой, под ногами и рядом с тобой — живёт, грохочет, торжествуя свои победы, железо (М. Г.).**

[Розенталь. Д. Э.](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=103#pp103)

Однородные члены предложения, находящиеся в середине предложения и имеющие значение попутного замечания, выделяются тире с двух сторон: **Всё, что могло приглушить звуки, — ковры, портьеры и мягкую мебель — Григ давно убрал из дома (Пауст.);** Всем — и Родину, и обоим Лычковым, и Володьке — вспоминаются белые лошади, маленькие пони, фейерверки, лодка с фонарями (Ч.).

[Лопатин, § 36.](http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=113#pp113)

Answer (score 1):

Серж, спасибо большое за ответ.

**Двоеточие** — это  классический вариант оформления предложения, вопросы же могут быть к варианту **с двумя тире**  при наличии **обособленного определения**.

Чисто визуально это оформление вызывает **вопросы,** недаром в учебных материалах перешли на двоеточие.  Откуда вопросы?  Такое оформление характерно **для вставок.** Если оформлять по правилу для вставок, то надо перенести запятую:

*Всё, что могло приглушить звуки — **ковры, портьеры и мягкую мебель,** — Григ давно убрал из дома.*

А это противоречит правилу для **обобщающих** слов. И что делать, может быть, надо как-то определить **область** применения правил?

Вот я и думаю, **как определить?**

В качестве версии:

Для предложений с **местоименными** обобщающими словами, как слово ***все***, два тире использовать нежелательно. Лучшим вариантом является **двоеточие**.

Comment: *Всё – ковры, портьеры и мягкую мебель*. Запятую переносить не надо, она закрывает придаточное, вклинивающееся в основную структуру. У Паустовского красиво и грамотно.

Comment: Интересная у вас терминология, плохо ее понимаю.

Comment: О каких разных? Я о той, что вы перенесли (перед вторым тире).

Comment: У Паустовского грамотное оформление по правилу обобщающих слов (с двумя тире), а по вставкам – нет.  Такое противоречие нежелательно, поэтому желательно использовать двоеточие, как в учебных текстах.

Comment: Почему по вставкам нет? Двоеточие по интонации здесь не очень подходит. Перед рядом голос повышается.

Comment: Постановка перед тире также запятой в качестве дополнительного пунктуационного знака связана с условиями контекста, т. е. обусловлена каким-либо другим правилом, например: С большой и сердечной любовью относились к Чехову и все люди попроще, с которыми он сталкивался: слуги, разносчики, носильщики, странники, почтальоны, – и не только с любовью, но и с тонкой чуткостью, с бережностью и с пониманием (Куприн) (запятая закрывает придаточное предложение и открывает присоединительную конструкцию);

Comment: Наряду с иными стихийными бедствиями, как-то: пожар, град, начисто выбивающий хлебные поля, ненастье или, наоборот, великая сушь, – есть в деревне ещё одно бедствие, о котором, может быть, и не знают многие городские люди (Солоухин) (запятая закрывает обособленный оборот с предложным сочетанием наряду с).

Comment: Если постановка запятой требуется структурой последней части предложения (стоящей после перечисления), то тире опускается и ставится только запятая, например: Владелец тщательно осведомляется о ценах на разные большие произведения, как-то: муку, пеньку, мёд и прочее, но покупает только небольшие безделушки… (Гоголь).

Comment: Серж,  интересные примеры, но решения разные. Думаю, что в каждом случае нужно объяснять знак на границе, одной  структурой не обойдешься. Интересная тема, но ее нужно провести к общему знаменателю, выражаясь математическим языком.  А то каждый "тянет одеяло в свою сторону".  И доводы интересные, но какие-то "лукавые".  Сначала решу (найду у классиков решение),  а потом подберу правило (или обоснование).

Comment: Меня очень привлекает метод блоков у Лопатина, по-моему он весьма хорош для таких задач.  Ведь там речь идет о границе между разными синтаксическими конструкциями. Совсем недавно был вопрос о двух тире, там я негласно применяла этот метод  при выборе одного или двух тире (решение было в пользу двух тире).

Comment: Sharon, запятая в нашем случае закрывает придаточное, а тире ставится, т.к. однородные члены не заканчивают собой предложение. По-моему, все логично и подпадает под описанное правило.

Comment: Что касается Лопатина, то он приводит примеры, но не объясняет запятую на стыке блоков.